# Does "Head of Curriculum and Instruction" make sense?

Tags: word-choice

I saw "Head of Curriculum and Instructuin" on a namecard. Is this business title is okay as English? This person is a high school teacher and manages the curriculum section.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the man or woman is the Head of the "Curriculum and Instruction" Section.  So Head of X, where X is the name of the section, is a fine business title.

Or they could be the head of two sections, Head of Curriculum and Head of Instruction.

Comment: I've certainly heard the title, although I can't say that I ever saw the incumbents do anything.

Comment: Perhaps that is why they were promoted to be the Section Head!